# Run Unix command using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

Is it possible to run a Unix command using a query in Oracle?

I want to run simple commands (like `df -h`) using a query.

Is this at all possible or am I wasting my time? I don't want to use a different language like Java or C to call a procedure, it needs to purely PL/SQL.

Comment: Have you seen `DBMS_SCHEDULER` yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058509/can-we-execute-unix-command-from-oracle10g-procedure

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DBMS_Scheduler

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_program
(
program_name => 'testScript',
program_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
program_action => '/home/someone/scripts/script.sh',
number_of_arguments => 0,
enabled => TRUE,
comments => 'Just a Test'
);
end;
/
```

and a little hosekeeping:

```
exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_program(PROGRAM_NAME => 'testScript');
```

Answer (score -1):

I just want to share an alternative approach for calling operating system commands. In this approach a simple web-service interface is set up for calling OS commands from SQL or PL/SQL. Details about this approach can be found [here](https://moizmuhammad.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/run-os-command-in-oracle-plsql).

Using the same approach, a step-by-step description of how to invoke SQL*Loader from SQL is described [here](https://moizmuhammad.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/run-oracle-sqlloader-from-sql-or-plsql).

Please note that in the above approach the web-service is defined in Python. Python comes pre-installed with most common Linux distributions (including Oracle Linux), however if you are on a Windows platform you may need to install Python 2.7.3

Comment: That's pretty crazy. You "command checks" that's supposed to restrict the security hole you're opening isn't effective at all given your use of `shell=True`. And the sql*loader thing is really perplexing - an external table is both much simpler and much more secure. (I'll not even comment about the required clear-text password in there.)

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the security flaw. I have fixed the issue by setting shell=False. Regarding External Table option i would say that it may be the best option in sc

Comment: Regarding External Table option i think it is not the preferred option in every scenario. There are cases where sql*loader is used directly from command shell. So what i have discussed is just an another way of invoking the sql*loader. Clear-text password issue may be mitigated by saving the username/password in the parameter file that can be specified in parFile option.

Comment: _There are cases where sql*loader is used directly from command shell._ Sure. What does that have to do with your blog post or this question though? If you're inside Oracle PL/SQL, use PL/SQL or external tables to do it.